# Buscar en dos arreglos los elementos con un mismo id y actualizar status en state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Estoy trabajando con React y quisiera saber como obtengo la posicion de **arr1** que contenga el mismo Id del **arry2** y actualizar el estatus de disponible a false, para despues pintarlo en mi componente..

```
this.state {
    arr1 = [
        { "id": 1, "dato": "mesa 1","disponible":true},
        { "id": 2, "dato": "mesa 2","disponible":true},
        { "id": 3, "dato": "mesa 3","disponible":true},
        { "id": 4, "dato": "mesa 4","disponible":true}
     ]
}

``

const arr2 =  [
        { "id": 4, "dato": "mesa 4" },
        { "id": 2, "dato": "mesa 2" }
    ]
``
```

Alguien que pudiera ayudarme un poco con en este problema.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontramos los indices a base del arr1 (recuerda que el indice inicia en 0)

```js
arr1 = [
        { "id": 1, "dato": "mesa 1","disponible":true},
        { "id": 2, "dato": "mesa 2","disponible":true},
        { "id": 3, "dato": "mesa 3","disponible":true},
        { "id": 4, "dato": "mesa 4","disponible":true}
     ]

arr2 =  [
        { "id": 4, "dato": "mesa 4" },
        { "id": 2, "dato": "mesa 2" }
    ]

arr2.forEach(buscar);

function buscar(value) {
  var valorId = value["id"];
  var indexArr1 = arr1.findIndex(i => i.id === valorId);
  console.log("arr2 con id:" + valorId + ", se encuentra en index arra1: " + indexArr1);
}
```

Comment: Gracias @kamousagi me funciono tu solucion